# How to fetch a url by proxy on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a website written in python that runs on the Google App Engine.  I need to fetch a url via a proxy.

Reading the documents says that I should be able to do this using urllib2, however it seems that what should work, isn't.

```
import urllib2, urllib

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://username:password@ipaddress:port'})
auth = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy, auth, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

conn = urllib2.urlopen('http://icanhazip.com/')
print conn.read()
```

Running the above code in my local development returns my IP.  Executing the same code on the site returns one of the 8.35.201.X address' used by Google.  It's almost like the ProxyHandler is being ignored.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use proxies to make requests on GAE.

At least this is true for Java (struggled with this just today. Google intentionaly restricted this). I am pretty sure this is also the case for Python.